# Is it possible to "mount" virtual CPU located in the cloud?

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

Is it possible to "mount" a virtual machine located in the cloud to my computer? Or in other terms to pipe some threads directly from my machine to the cloud and get the results back to virtually improve my computer's power.

I searched something existing with virtual machines or docker but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Even if you could, there wouldn't be any point; the latency involved in sending data over the network would be orders of magnitude greater than any speedup you would gain.

Comment: Doing this at thread level might be a bit optimistic, but if I interpret your question freely you're asking about distributed computing in general. Maybe have a look at Mesos, which allows you to use Docker containers to do this. It's not an easy 'pipe command' subject though